# Calculating lower bound with stirlings approximation

Tags: approximation, lower-bound

We have this exercise in school, where we are to calculate the lower bound of an algorithm.
We know that the lower bound is: Log_6((3*n)! / n!^3) and we are to use stirlings approximation to approximate n!. When appling stirlings approximation we get:

log_6((sqrt(2*pi*3*n)*((3*n)/e)^(3*n) * e^alpha)/(sqrt(2*pi*n)*(n/e)^n * e^alpha)^3)

Now our problem is that every time we try expanding this formula with simple logarithm properties, such as log(a/b) = log(a)-log(b), log(a*b) = log(a)+log(b), log(a^b) = b*log(a) and lastly for sqrt log(sqrt(a)) = log(a^1/2) = 1/2 * log(a), we get a result where to dominating expression will be something with n*log(n) * constant. Now we know from the teacher that we have to find a linear lower bound, so this is wrong.

We have been using 2 days on this and are about to give up. Can anybody maybe help us?

Thanks in advance!